# ggplot showing a trend with more than 1 variables across y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe df where I need to see the comparison of the trend between weeks

```
df
Col Mon Tue Wed
 1  47  164 163
 2  110 168 5
 3  31  146 109
 4  72  140 170
 5  129 185 37
 6  41  77  96
 7  85  26  41
 8  123 15  188
 9  14  23  163
 10 152 116 82
 11 118 101 5
```

Right now I can only plot 2 variables like below. But I need to see for Tuesday and Wednesday as well

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=Col,y=Mon))+geom_line()
```

Comment: After this code par(new = T) , add Tue. If you want separately, par(mfrow =  c(2,2))

Answer (score 1):

You can either add a

```
geom_line(aes(x = Col, y = Mon), col = 1)
```

for each day, or you would need to restructure your data frame using a function like `gather` so your new columns are col, day, value. Without reformatting the data, your result would be

```
ggplot(data=df)+geom_line(aes(x=Col,y=Mon), col = 1) + geom_line(aes(x=Col,y=Tue), col = 2) + geom_line(aes(x=Col,y=Wed), col = 3)
```

with a restructure it would be

```
ggplot(data=df)+geom_line(aes(x=Col,y=Val, col = Day))
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way would be to get the data in long format and then plot

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -Col) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(factor(Col), value, col = key, group = key) + geom_line()
```

[image]